# Is there optimal sparse and minimum energy solution?

Tags: soft-question, definitions, regularization

I am interested to know if anyone worked on the the inverse solution of the problem defined below, which means I want to find $\tilde{y}$.

$M_{\delta}^{\alpha}[\tilde{y}]=\|A\tilde{y}-\tilde{b}\|_{L_2}^2 + \alpha\|\tilde{y}\|_{L_2}^2+(1-\alpha)\|\tilde{y}\|_{L_1},  \\
y_{\alpha}=argminM_{\delta}^{\alpha}[\tilde{y}],$

where $M_{\delta}^{\alpha}[\tilde{y}]$ is a smoothing and sparse functional, $\alpha$ is a regularization parameter and $y_{\alpha}$ is a regularized solution that provides a global minimum of the functional $M$.

I have seen using $L_2$ and $L_1$ separately but not together. But it appears in my work the combination may be helpful. My question if this problem is analysed if so if there is a optimal method to choose ${\alpha}$?

Comment: This is known as *elastic net* regularization and has been studied quite a bit; see, e.g., https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.0796.pdf.

Comment: @ChristianClason Thank you so much.